# Assignment and Binding

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a problem.Let's explain this:
I create a DataTable 'DataT' variable and added row to this variable.SameTime i have datagridview. After i assingmented 'DataT' to DataSource property of DataGridView.
I get 'DataT' Rows.Count property.It's value 10.But this value decrease from 10 to 5 when i removed 5 Rows of DataGridView.
So why decrease my value i just remove Rows of DataGridView but i did not remove rows of 'DataT' although rows count of 'DataT' decrease from 10 to 5.
I have not solve this problem.

EDIT:
Yes i bound datatable.But same problem there is other state.I explain with a example:

```
DataTable Table1 = new DataTable();
DataTable Table2 = new DataTable();
DataRow Rows;

private void Form1_Load(.......)
{
    Tablo1.Columns.Add("Column1");
    Tablo1.Columns.Add("Column2");

    Rows = Table1.NewRow();
    Rows[0] = "Hello";
    Rows[1] = "Word";
    Table1.Rows.Add(Rows);

    Rows = Table1.NewRow();
    Rows[0] = "Hello";
    Rows[1] = "Word";

    Table1.Rows.Add(Rows);

    Table2 = Table1;
    datagridview1.DataSource = Table1;      
    //This datagridview1 has 2 Rows and Table1 has 2 Rows.  

    datagridview1.Rows.RemoveAt(0); 
    //I am Removing one Row of datagridview1.Not from Table1.

    //But Automatic removing Rows from Table1.
    //Result=datagridview1 has 1 Row and Table1 has 1 Row.Why do remove rows from Table1?
   //Even Rows Remove from Table2 when i remove rows from datagridview1.    
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you are doing, what the problem is or what you have tried doing to solve it. Especially since there is no code to illustrate any of it

Comment: How do you remove the rows from DataGridView? If it is bound to DataTable this binding works in both directions.

Comment: ???? What have DataGridView / DataTable in common with byte[].

Comment: Sorry i am so new on this form....I incorrect edited......
I added new command.
I thank you.

Comment: The actual issue here is data-binding. The GridView is _supposed_ to pass edit/add/delete on to the DataTable.

Comment: When you see DataBinding as 'a problem', you could try `datagridview1.DataSource = Table1.Rows.ToList();`. I didn't test that.

Comment: I thank you Henk for so useful help.By the way i am sorry to late comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) pointed out in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652465/assigment-and-binding/41653728?noredirect=1#comment70507089_41652465) there are two reasons making `Table2` to change

- since `Table1` is used as `DataSource` for grid any changes in the grid will be reflected in it. This is expected behavior of `GridView`.

  `GridView` has its own `Rows` collection that is updated when one sets `DataSource`. Any changes to `Rows` collection (like removing item) are applied to `DataTable` set as data source. As result `datagridview1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);` actually *indirectly* removes row from the object referenced by `Table1`.
- Both of your variables (`Table1` and `Table2`) point to the same object - so whenever anything happens to the DataTable (i.e. row removed by GridView) the change is visible when you check either of variables.

  Following code performs "shallow copy" when you seem to expect complete clone similar to behavior of `int`:

  ```
  Table2 = Table1;
  ```

  After that assignment both `Table1` and `Table2` refer to `DataTable` created on `DataTable Table1 = new DataTable();` line.

  See more [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: I thank You for Help and Comment.I am reasearching this Copy Methods."Shallow and Deep Copy".

Comment: Deep/Shallow copy is not really the core issue here. It's about databinding. The GridView does create its own Rows collection (deep copy).

Comment: Would you explain a little more?I binding just do assigment.
So how do i binding?

Comment: @HenkHolterman good point that there are actually 2 somewhat unrelated concerns - I've updated post with your comments (linked to comment on question too) - please check if you have time (and mark this comment obsolete when done).

Comment: So have to i use Deep Copy?.Or Second variable is independent from variable1.Have to Both variable add Rows for each separataly?.